# PHP 5.4 not available for windows + Apache?

Tags: php

I'd like to install the new PHP 5.4 on my Windows machine. I'm running Apache 2.2 on it. Reading the info on http://windows.php.net/download/, it says "If you are using PHP with Apache 1 or Apache2 from apache.org you need to use the VC6 versions of PHP". I guess I'm in that case, I just donloaded Apache from apache.org.

However, there are no VC6 versions available of PHP 5.4, not even of PHP 5.3. How can I install PHP 5.4 on my Windows machine then ?

Answer (score 1):

You needed to keep reading a bit further down the page.

> "VC9 versions of Apache can be fetched at [Apache Lounge](http://www.apachelounge.com/). We use
>   their binaries to build the Apache SAPIs."

Just be sure to get the 32 bit version on the download page.

Comment: I did read that, but does that mean that I need to install an unofficial version of Apache just to be able to run it with PHP ?